# Can governments require administrators of groups on social media platforms to buy licenses?

Tags: internet, privacy, data-protection

The Kenyan government now wants administrators of WhatsApp groups and other social media platforms to pay for licenses. Is this possible with the GDPR, Facebook privacy policy, etc., as the proposed law also requires such administrators to keep all the data of the users of the platform and submit the same to the authorities when required. 
[Bill summary](https://citizentv.co.ke/news/govt-wants-kenyans-to-pay-license-fee-for-whatsapp-groups-283631/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Kenya legislature passes such a law, they can impose such a requirement on Kenyans who want to create such social media groups. Note that this is a license from the Kenyan government, not a copyright or trademark license. In effect, it is a tax on running a social media group, along with various regulations.

I have no idea if this bill is at all likely to pass. If it does pass, it might be hard to enforce, as it would probably require cooperation from Facebook and other social media platforms, and the companies which run those platforms are not located in Kenya, and might not cooperate.

Answer (score -1):

This has absolutely nothing to do with GDPR. GDPR only applies to data held on EU residents. Kenya is not part of the EU.

Comment: Welcome to [Law]!  This would be better posted as a comment on the original question, not as a new answer, so it may be removed.  As you gain reputation on this site, you'll gain the ability to comment on questions and answer. (In the meantime, I've approved your proposed edit on the original question, but it still needs one more vote to go through.)